# how to delete in the document on Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this collection and I want to delete "this my comment" as shown below. How is it done with mongodb?

```
"comments" : [ { "comment" : "this is my comment", "user" : "admin" } ] }
```

This is my query, but, it doesn't work:

```
db.article.remove( { "comment" : "this is my comment"} )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pull operator to remove the comment. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

```
db.article.update(   
{ },
{ "$pull": { "comments": { "comment" : "this is my comment" } } },
{ "multi": true }
)
```

Comment: i have this WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })

Comment: Updated my answer, you dont need elemMatch. Try with this.

Comment: Strange! I tried this command on my local with a sample doc and it was working properly.

Comment: it possible to make it on php  ?